# Validation for text area doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I have developed a form to get user input and in text area and I want to avoid user typing special characters.

Following is the code of the form and the function I used for validation. The problem is even after using the validation, it accepts special characters entered by the user. I can't find what has gone wrong. Please help me.

Thanks in advance

index.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page language="java" session="true" %> 

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/scripts.js"></script>

    <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<form name = "MyForm" action="SubmitUser" method ="post" onsubmit="validate()">

<textarea rows="6" cols="150" name="comment" value="">
                </textarea>


<input type = "submit" name ="sub" value="Submit">

  </body>
</html>
```

Following is the scripts.js

```
function validate() {
    var iChars = "!@#$%^&*()+=-[]\\\';,./{}|\":<>?";
    for (var i = 0; i < document.MyForm.comment.value.length; i++) {
        if (iChars.indexOf(document.MyForm.comment.value.charAt(i)) != -1) {
            alert ("This Field has special characters. \nSpecial Characters are not allowed");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not stopping the submit event of your form. To halt the normal flow, you may modify your code below logic:

```
<form name = "MyForm" action="SubmitUser" method ="post">

<textarea rows="6" cols="150" name="comment" value="">
                </textarea>


<input type = "button" name ="sub" value="Submit" onclick="validate()">
```

and modify your javascript as :

```
function validate(){
   var iChars = "!@#$%^&*()+=-[]\\\';,./{}|\":<>?";
   for (var i = 0; i < document.MyForm.comment.value.length; i++) {
     if (iChars.indexOf(document.MyForm.comment.value.charAt(i)) != -1) {
       alert ("This Field has special characters. \nSpecial Characters are not allowed");
     return false;
    }
  document.MyForm.submit();
}
```

Hope you have got the logic to do validations!

Answer (score 0):

You want to use RegExp.

```
var iChars = new RegExp(/[@!#$%^&*()+=\[\]\-\\\';,./{}|\":<>?]/)
var x = "AB@"
iChars.test(x) // true
```

or simply, if \W meets your needs,

```
var re = new RegExp(/\W/)
re.text(x)
```

See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) for more on regexp

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the **[match() method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp)** :

```
var comment = document.MyForm.comment.value; 
var res = comment.match(/\W/);
```

`\W` to match any non word character.

Then your `res` result is an array of matching strings just test if `res.length>0` then the inputted comment is not valid.

Then your function would be:

```
function validate(){
  var comment = document.MyForm.comment.value; 
  var res = comment.match(/\W/);
  if(res.length>0) alert ("This Field has special characters. \nSpecial Characters are not allowed");
}
```